# OpenCL: offset for accessing float2*/float4*/... elements

Tags: opencl

I currently have something like this in my kernel code:

```
func(__global float2 *array, __global float *buffer) {
    float *vector[2];
    vector[0] = array.s0;
    vector[1] = array.s1;
```

So I can do something like this later in the code:

```
vector[vec_off][index] = buffer[i];
```

Basically, I want to be able to access the elements of a float2 in my code based on a calculated index. The point is to be able to easily expand it to a float4/float16 vector later on.

Currently I get a (-11) error (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) when I try to do vector[0] = array.x; Which I guess means I'm not allowed to write it (like that?) in OpenCL.
If it's not just a syntax error, I should be able to do this by accessing each element of array using an offset, so I would have:

```
array.s0 = array
array.s1 = array + offset
...
array.sf = array + 15 * offset
```

I do not know however how a floatn is stored in memory. Is the .s1 part stored right after the .s0? Is that is the case, then offset would just be the size of array.s0, right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use calculated index to access `float2` elements you can use `union` or cast directly to `float*`:

**1. Using `union`**

Define the following `union`:

```
union float_type
{
    float2 data2;
    float data[2];
};
```

and then cast `float2` array on the fly and access elements using calculated index:

```
func(__global float2 *array, __global float *buffer) {
     float foo = ((__global union float_type*)array)[1].data[1];
}
```

**2. cast to `float*`**

```
func(__global float2 *array, __global float *buffer) {
     float foo = ((__global float*)&array[1])[1];
}
```

Comment: @MaiLongdong can you elaborate?

Comment: Devs tend to use `union` approach (I think for better readability) but casting directly works fine too.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the way I did it in the question works in C but not in OpenCL?

Comment: `Currently I get a (-11) error (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) when I try to do vector[0] = array.x;` - this is failing because you are trying to assign a value to a pointer. Even if you would change it to `vector[0] = &array.x;` this will still fail but on an attempt to get an address of vector element.